# UI Automation (UIA) RaiseAutomationPropertyChangedEvent Exception "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation, argumentexception

I'm currently trying to implement `Move(double x, double y)` as part of `ITransformProvider` within the UI Automation Provider API. The specifications say that after moving an element, I must raise a BoundingRectangleProperty changed event.

```
    // Save original location to raise an event
    System.Windows.Rect oldBoundingRectangle = BoundingRectangle;

    //  ... Move logic code here ...

    // Raise BoundingRectanglePropertyChanged event if clients are listening
    if (AutomationInteropProvider.ClientsAreListening)
    {
            AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedArgs = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs(AutomationElementIdentifiers.BoundingRectangleProperty, oldBoundingRectangle, BoundingRectangle);
            AutomationInteropProvider.RaiseAutomationPropertyChangedEvent(this, propertyChangedArgs);
    }
```

`this` implements `IRawElementProviderFragment` in the code above.

The call to `AutomationInteropProvider.RaiseAutomationPropertyChangedEvent()` raises an ArgumentException with message "**Value does not fall within the expected range.**"

This is a rather generic error message and I'm having trouble isolating the cause. Both the old and new parameters to the event args are of type System.Windows.Rect, as is the BoundingRectangle property.

I've even tried using RedGate Reflector to decompile UIAutomationProvider.dll and generate the debug symbols. The exception gets thrown when we call `ValidateArgumentNonNull(e, "e");` within `AutomationInteropProvider::RaiseAutomationPropertyChangedEvent(IRawElementProviderSimple element, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e).` Except the body of `ValidateArgumentNonNull()` never gets called (breakpoints within never gets hit). I suspect that decompilating the dll is not reliable and this is a false lead.

On an unrelated note, I'm able to raise property changed events for IsSelected.

Has anyone else experienced this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider to use  white project (https://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/UIAv3/) which is a automation framework which use a custom implementation of UIAutomation (https://github.com/TestStack/UIAComWrapper) which is a C# wrapper of UIAutomation3.0

Answer (score 0):

After bottoming out debugging this logically, we started trying random values to see what works in a black-box testing fashion.

```
if (AutomationInteropProvider.ClientsAreListening)
{
    // Passing anything other than null for the oldValue and newValue results in an ArgumentException of "Value does not fall within expected range" Not sure why?
    AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedArgs = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs(AutomationElementIdentifiers.BoundingRectangleProperty, null, null);
    AutomationInteropProvider.RaiseAutomationPropertyChangedEvent(this, propertyChangedArgs);
}
```

I'm still not sure why providing null for both the oldValue and newValue works. The documentation shows no indication I should pass anything other than the old and new value. UIAVerify tests are passing so I'm working off the assumption that this is the correct solution. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft documentation states that BoundingRectangle cannot be used in PropertyCondition.

> The property parameter cannot be BoundingRectangleProperty.

If one tries to pass any value other then null as the property value of the BoundingRectangle, then an ArgumentException is raised with "Value does not fall within the expected range.".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.propertycondition.-ctor